# How do I add buttons and fields on the header of the Kanban view with ODOO 12?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-12

I'm working on odoo 12, I tried to add a field or a button like on the header of the Kanban view (product_template view) in order to add searching filters like those:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="KanbanView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.oe_kanban_add" t-operation="after">
            <t t-if="widget.model == 'product.template'">
                <button>
                    class="oe_button oe_highlight"
                    type="button">My Button</button>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

And this code:

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_kanban_gimmo" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field  name="name">Searching</field>
            <field  name="model">product.template</field>
            <field  name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view"/>

            <field  name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                    <header position="inside">
                        <button
                    class="oe_button oe_highlight"
                    type="button">My Button</button>
                    </header>
                </xpath>
                </field>
        </record>
</odoo>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 12 please use this `<t t-if="widget.modelName == 'product.template'">` instead of `<t t-if="widget.model == 'product.template'">`